# Finding the energy eigenvalue for the second excited state of a quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I am self studying quantum mechanics and currently trying to find the energy eigenvalue for the *second* excited state of a quantum harmonic oscillator:

$$\psi_2=N_2\left\{\frac{4x^2}{\alpha^2}-2\right\}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}$$
$$\alpha=\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{mk}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$$
$$ E\psi=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\mathit\psi}{dx^2}+\frac{kx^2}{2}\psi$$

The energies permitted by the boundary conditions are

$$E_v=(v+\frac 12)\hbar\omega$$

It follows that the energy corresponding to the second excited state is $\frac 52\hbar\omega$. I know this, however I would like to find this value by using the differential equation. I managed to do this for the ground state and first excited state ($v=0, v=1$, respectively), however I'm struggling with this, and can't find any existing help online; I can't see any glaring issues with my calculus, nor my algebra: the issue seems to be when i try to factorise $\psi$ out after taking the second derivative. I don't think this should be as difficult as I'm finding it!

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the problem to compute several eigenvalues for harmonic oscillator? What code did you use?

Comment: Plug $\psi_2$in  on the right side of Schroedinger's equation and look if you get $\frac{5}{2}\hbar \omega\psi_2$ as result. If not (or may be you get $3/2\hbar\omega\psi_2$ because of the numerotation of the $\psi_n$), then may be the $\psi_2$ used is wrong. Of course you need the formula for $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$.

Comment: @FredericThomas I have tried giving the function to an online derivative calculator to solve, but it couldn't do it. The general form of the wavefunctions for a QHO is $\psi_v=N_vH_v(y)e^\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}$, with $y=\frac{x}{\alpha}$; that is the product of a normalisation constant, a physicist's hermite polynomial, and a gaussian function. The second hermite polynomial is $H_2(y)=4y^2-2$, so I think my $\psi_2$ is correct. I don't _need_ to solve this problem (it's not a textbook problem), but I'd quite like to, since I've spent lots of time on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting overwhelmed by superfluous constants and signs. Note that
$$
\partial^2((2x^2-1) e^{-x^2/2})\\
=\partial((4x-x(2x^2-1) ) e^{-x^2/2})\\
=(-6x^2+5+ x^2(2x^2-5))e^{-x^2/2}\\
=(-5+x^2)(2x^2-1)e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
Note the first parenthesis is just $2V-2E_2$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.